# Delete OEM or Windows Recovery when dual booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10, which is currently installed.

My partition table looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  368MB  367MB  primary  fat32        diag
 2      368MB   735MB  367MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 3      735MB   860GB  859GB  primary  ntfs
 4      860GB   860GB  472MB  primary  ntfs         diag
```

partition `1` is a OEM partition, `2` is `System Reserved`, most probably for windows; `3` is my Windows `C:` drive; and `4` is a Windows recovery partition.

I have about 130GB of unallocated space which I would want to install Ubuntu on. However, when installing , the free space is considered "unusable" and I cannot dual boot/install Ubuntu. After Googling this, it appears that only 4 partitions are allowed. I do have a Windows recovery disk. Which partition OEM or Windows Recovery (Since I have a recovery disk) (`1` or `4` respectively) should I remove?

Thanks,

Corgs